# angular2 protractor: npm e2e failed - A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow

Tags: angular, protractor

I am successfull with `npm test` however still failed to run `npm e2e` for the project angular2-quickstart

A Chrome instance appears with Disable developer mode extensions for few seconds then an error throws out.
[image]

```
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 e2e c:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\my-proj
> tsc && concurrently "http-server -s" "protractor protractor.config.js" --kill-
others --success first

[1] [12:29:33] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[1] [12:29:33] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[1] AppDir: ./
[1]   Suite: QuickStart E2E Tests
[1] A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
[1]     failed - should display: My First Angular 2 App
[1]   Suite failed: QuickStart E2E Tests
[1] [12:29:48] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[1] [12:29:48] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[1] [12:29:48] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[1] [12:29:48] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
[1] protractor protractor.config.js exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] http-server -s exited with code 1
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

need to the web app running at port 8080 while doing e2e testing or run `npm start` to find the web app port, ie `3000` then change `protractor.config.js` baseUrl to that port :

```
// Base URL for application server
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
```